# How to duplicate screen in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am new to the use of ubuntu and did not manage to duplicate the screen of my monitor to a tv through hdmi.

Comment: Does the TV show up in Settings/Displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on a machine originally installed with Windows use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, where <kbd>Super</kbd> is the key with the Windows icon.